# 'if' 'or'- statement in dictionary always returns TRUE

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, if-statement

I have this python dictionary:

```
event_dict = {
            'False': 1,
            'Hit': 2,
            'MP1': 3,
            'MP2': 4,
            'MP3': 5,
            'M_False': 6,
            'M_Hit': 7,
            'OGT': 8,
            'PMC': 9,
            'S  4': 10,
            'actiCAP Data On': 11,
            'boundary': 12
 }
```

And I wrote this code to check if the entries "TriEVE", "TriODD", "TriPMC" are in the dictionary (They're not!):

```
if "TriEVE" or "TriODD" or "TriPMC" in event_dict:
    print('THIS SESSION HAS BAD ANNOTATIONS!!!!!!!')
```

The code returns:

```
THIS SESSION HAS BAD ANNOTATIONS!!!!!!!
```

I tried to use the 'if'-statement with just one input (without 'or'), like:

```
if "TriEVE" in event_dict:
    print('THIS SESSION HAS BAD ANNOTATIONS!!!!!!!')
    print(subject)
```

The code returns nothing, as expected.

Why can't I use 'or'-statements in this case? Is there a smarter way of searching for more than one dictionary entry at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you want

```
if "TriEVE" in event_dict.keys() or "TriODD" in event_dict.keys() or "TriPMC" in event_dict.keys():
```

this is because anything not-zero or non-None is evaluated to True in Python
Since it seems that you wanted to search the keys of the dict, you have to use .keys() or .values() if you want to look at values. The object itself isn't useful in this context